# move_uploaded_file save empty file only in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have big problem with Internet Explorer even 11, in my code im using move_uploaded_file function. And this function save blank file on server with 0KB however, its working on another browser like chrome, firefox etc. and the function save full file. i have multipart enctype in form and permission 777 in directory.

Can someone help me what i should to do to save this file with success?

```
if (!empty($_FILES['INPUT']['name'])) {
        if ($_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/png" 
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/jpg"
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/JPG"
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/JPEG"
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/PNG"
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"
            || $_FILES["INPUT"]["type"] == "image/x-png") {
            $img = $_FILES['INPUT']['name'].".png";
            $target_file = '../assets/directory/'.$img;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['INPUT']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
            return "/assets/directory/".$_FILES['INPUT']['name'].".png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES["INPUT"]["type"]);`

Comment: also show us the upload code

Comment: var_dump return string(10) "image/jpeg"

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES['INPUT']);`

Comment: INTERNET EXPLORER
`c array(5) {["name"]=>string(9) "test4.JPG"["type"]=>string(10) "image/jpeg"["tmp_name"]=>string(14) "/tmp/phphQplne"["error"]=>int(0)["size"]=>int(0) } `

CHROME
`c array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "test4.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpxbazEi" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(84203) }`

Comment: Why did you add .png? try after remove ".png".

Comment: I'm extremely irritated by the size. Could you show us how you upload the image?

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="{$CurrentPage.Link}"  target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="generator-form">`

`<input style="height: 34px; margin-left: 57px; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="kid_pdf" name="kid_pdf" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/JPG, image/JPEG, image/PNG" onchange="show(this)" required="required"/>`

Comment: if your file name is 'test4.JPG' then after appending '.png' it will be 'test4.JPG.png'. Is it correct name/extension of image file?

Comment: if i dont add .png its the same situation... EMPTY FILE... im extremely irritated too...

Comment: `name="kid_pdf"` shouldn't the file be in `$_FILES['kid_pdf']`?

Comment: Yeah i change it only for stackoverflow question

Comment: Why its not working only in IE? that's the question... another MIME? IE cant see that this is image or something?

Comment: try `image/*` as only mime type in accept

Comment: still size is 0

Comment: just tested it locally. works as expected. Is there any javascript in your page, messing with the input?

Comment: i have function show() and this function validate the IMG. but when i delete it and deleted onclick event its the same size=0

Comment: Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was with target="_blank" when i removed it everything works.